# Is there a reason Ruby/Rails has not made nested indexing safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, language-design, monkeypatching

A feature of ruby that I've always considered nice is the `nil` default for indexing/hash lookup, e.g.

```
[1, 2, 3][42]         # => nil
{ foo: :bar }[:spam]  # => nil
```

Is there a reason why, in Ruby's design or Ruby on Rails' core extensions, this has not been extended to work for nested lookups (rather than throwing `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`)?

For example:

```
{ foo: [1, 2, 3] }[:bar][0][:baz]   # => nil
[[[]]][12][1][1]                    # => nil
```

In my, perhaps nieve, understanding it would be as simple as:

```
class NilClass
  def [](_); end
end
```

Comment: Look at the try command it does what you want.

Comment: I am aware of `try`. Since nested lookups are very common, I was wondering why this case wasn't optimized for.

Comment: How would you tell the difference between `h[:k1][:k2]` and `nil[:k2]`? Your proposed patch to `NilClass` goes too far, it would hide bugs in the name of convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some languages, like Objective-C, make method calls on a `nil` object return `nil` so these sorts of errors melt away.

Rails has always taken the path of having a "whiny `nil`" where any method calls hard fail. This has become expected behaviour.

If you want to patch your NilClass, do it completely:

```
def NilClass
  def method_missing(*args)
    # Do nothing, return nil
  end
end
```

You can add this in `config/initializers` to suppress errors, but be warned, this may hide legitimate problems and make your application perform in unpredictable ways. For example. `nil.id` actually returns a value.